# Onclick event doesnt work on Mobile phones

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, html5-canvas

I believe this is a unique issue as I can not find a solution anywhere on SO.

I've added a button in html5 canvas in Flash and published as html5, buttons work, however, on mobile devices with touch screens it doesn't.

I've also replaced "click" with "touchstart" - but it doesnt work, can anybody help me?

```
    this.movieClip_2.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame.bind(this));

    function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame()
    {
        this.gotoAndPlay(24);
    }
```

Thanks Anton

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.movieClip_2.addEventListener("click", clickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame);

function clickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //I don't know the MovieClip object are you trying to trigger the gotoAndPlay() method
    this.gotoAndPlay(24);
    //or this.movieClip_2.gotoAndPlay(24);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this creates a blank canvas though. Just, by the way, I'm a graphic designer and dont know anything about AS3 - Should I give you more sample code?